# Bad video quality and only 3 fps

Tags: avconv

There are a few things wrong with the quality of the output file when I run this command.

```
arecord -d 0 -r 48000 -c 2 -f S16_LE -t wav -D sysdefault:CARD=tc358743 | avconv -t 0 -i pipe:0 -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -r 30 -acodec aac -ar 48000 -vcodec flv -strict experimental -y -f flv test.flv
```

The audio seems okay at the moment but, if I'm reading it correctly (at the very bottom of the output below), the fps is about 3 and the quality is at 31, which I understand is the worse. This is the output during the process.

I'm looking to get 30 fps (ideally 60 if possible).

I'm pretty new to this, any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

```
ffmpeg version 3.2.10-1~deb9u1+rpt2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb9u1+rpt2' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --arch=armhf --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, wav, from 'pipe:0':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x172e110] ioctl(VIDIOC_G_PARM): Inappropriate ioctl for device
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x172e110] Time per frame unknown
Input #1, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 927.631204, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: rawvideo (UYVY / 0x59565955), uyvy422, 1280x720, 120 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Output #0, flv, to 'test.flv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: flv1 (flv) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p, 1280x720, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 120 fps, 1k tbn, 120 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 flv
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> flv1 (flv))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> aac (native))
[wav @ 0x1728730] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x172e110] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
overrun!!! (at least 9513.101 ms long)44kB time=00:00:00.97 bitrate=2890.9kbits/s speed=0.0987x
overrun!!! (at least 25.077 ms long) 363kB time=00:00:01.84 bitrate=1614.1kbits/s speed=0.162x
overrun!!! (at least 254.192 ms long)421kB time=00:00:02.97 bitrate=1159.1kbits/s speed=0.226x
overrun!!! (at least 93.349 ms long) 441kB time=00:00:03.86 bitrate= 935.3kbits/s speed=0.263x
overrun!!! (at least 198.942 ms long)461kB time=00:00:04.97 bitrate= 758.6kbits/s speed=0.303x
overrun!!! (at least 155.909 ms long)526kB time=00:00:06.14 bitrate= 701.0kbits/s speed=0.337x
frame=   54 fps=2.8 q=31.0 Lsize=     534kB time=00:00:06.67 bitrate= 655.6kbits/s speed=0.352x
```

Running different commands to see what happens. This command:

```
avconv -t 0 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -y newtest.h264
```

Slowly builds up to 40 fps but the result is still poor. Feels like it's 5 fps not 40. The CPU percentage when running this is 65-70%. Output is:

```
ffmpeg version 3.2.10-1~deb9u1+rpt2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb9u1+rpt2' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --arch=armhf --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x16d4600] ioctl(VIDIOC_G_PARM): Inappropriate ioctl for device
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x16d4600] Time per frame unknown
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 5015.769341, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (UYVY / 0x59565955), uyvy422, 1280x720, 59.94 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
No pixel format specified, yuv422p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264 @ 0x16d77e0] using cpu capabilities: ARMv6 NEON
[libx264 @ 0x16d77e0] profile High 4:2:2, level 3.2, 4:2:2 8-bit
Output #0, h264, to 'newtest.h264':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264), yuv422p, 1280x720, q=-1--1, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 1813 fps= 37 q=-1.0 Lsize=    3218kB time=00:00:30.24 bitrate= 871.5kbits/s dup=1700 drop=0 speed=0.617x
video:3218kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000000%
[libx264 @ 0x16d77e0] frame I:8     Avg QP:14.00  size:170114
[libx264 @ 0x16d77e0] frame P:1805  Avg QP:15.46  size:  1071
[libx264 @ 0x16d77e0] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x16d77e0] mb P  I16..4:  0.4%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  2.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:97.6%
[libx264 @ 0x16d77e0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 43.4% 28.3% 19.2% inter: 1.1% 0.8% 0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x16d77e0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 61% 26%  8%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x16d77e0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 68% 12% 17%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x16d77e0] kb/s:871.45
```

Running this command:

```
avconv -t 0 -i /dev/video0 -r 60 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -y newtest.flv
```

(just specifying a different output file format, results in a CPU usage of about 30% and produces this output:

```
avconv -t 0 -i /dev/video0 -r 60 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -y newtest.flv
ffmpeg version 3.2.10-1~deb9u1+rpt2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb9u1+rpt2' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --arch=armhf --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x527620] ioctl(VIDIOC_G_PARM): Inappropriate ioctl for device
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x527620] Time per frame unknown
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 6071.912862, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (UYVY / 0x59565955), uyvy422, 1280x720, 120 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
No pixel format specified, yuv422p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264 @ 0x52a870] using cpu capabilities: ARMv6 NEON
[libx264 @ 0x52a870] profile High 4:2:2, level 3.2, 4:2:2 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x52a870] 264 - core 148 r2748 97eaef2 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2016 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
Output #0, flv, to 'newtest.flv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv422p, 1280x720, q=-1--1, 60 fps, 1k tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.64.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  158 fps=4.1 q=-1.0 Lsize=     878kB time=00:00:30.70 bitrate= 234.2kbits/s speed=0.803x
video:874kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.385400%
[libx264 @ 0x52a870] frame I:1     Avg QP:20.00  size: 68854
[libx264 @ 0x52a870] frame P:157   Avg QP: 8.93  size:  5261
[libx264 @ 0x52a870] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x52a870] mb P  I16..4:  1.4%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  7.7%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:90.9%
[libx264 @ 0x52a870] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 28.1% 13.8% 13.4% inter: 3.4% 2.7% 2.3%
[libx264 @ 0x52a870] i16 v,h,dc,p: 76% 22%  1%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x52a870] i8c dc,h,v,p: 88%  4%  7%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x52a870] kb/s:231.42
```

Comment: `-c:v` and `-vcodec` are the exact same thing, The second one (`flv`) is being used, and the first (`libx264`) is being ignored. Was that the intended codec?

Comment: Thanks, I can remove the second one. Any idea how to get the fps up?

Comment: How do you even know what the FPS will be with the other codec?

Comment: I've tried both codecs, it's the same. I've also tried different output formats too.

Comment: What’s the CPU usage? It could be the capture and not the encode. What happens when you pipe raw data to dev/null without encoding?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean (sorry) but I've done avconv -t 0 -i /dev/video0 -f flv -y newtest.flv and it's the same  result. Please let me know if you meant something else.

Comment: That still encodes. Look at the ffmpeg output. It will tell you what codec is in use.

Comment: I get 25% CPU useage when running avconv -t 0 -i /dev/video0 -f flv /dev/null. I'll add the output to the question.

Comment: Aha. Running avconv -t 0 -i /dev/video0 -f null /dev/null gets 60 fps!

Comment: So is encoding the issue then? Any way to sort that or?

Comment: Try the ultrafast preset.

Comment: avconv -t 0 -i /dev/video0 -preset ultrafast -f flv -y newtest.flv has the same low fps (about 3 or 4).

Comment: You need to do some basic troubleshooting and experimenting on your own. I can’t see your screen. I don’t know what the ffmpeg output is, I can’t see how much CPU is being used, I don’t know what processor your computer has. I can’t troubleshoot for you. You need to give WAY more information. I’m just making guesses here, because you not got giving any information to work with.

Comment: Apologies. Appreciate your help and willing to give as much information as I can. I've added a couple of commands to the original question detail and added CPU %'s and ffmpeg's output for both.